# MinCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata is greater than compileSdkVersion

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, metadata

**React-native Android Platform building issue**

> The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a dependency's AAR metadata (`META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties`) is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30). Dependency: androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1.

I have tried many solutions with Gradle, SDK and many other solutions from GitHub and StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Found The Solution. Just add this code in android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
   configurations.all {
       resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.react:react-native:0.65.2' 
            //select Version you used
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is related to react native library.
the complete details about the issue are here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210

also, you can check the answer with solutions in stackoverflow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74412023/12146710